# iOS Settings-App URL Scheme for Settings/Safari/Extensions

Tags: swift, settings, url-scheme

After full-on research on these URL-Schemes, I'm still desperate for the correct scheme for:

**Settings -> Safari -> Extensions**

So far, I managed to work my way up to 'Safari' with this syntax: **"App-Prefs:SAFARI"**. (on an actual device)

I realized that the syntax **"&path="** does work sometimes, but I can't figure out the correct syntax to get to the 'Extensions' section.

Any help will be welcomed, as I'm out of ideas 
Thx you all!

Comment: Update: I got the right Scheme to get to Safari/Downloads with this syntax: "App-Prefs:SAFARI&path=DOWNLOADS",
but no - it doesn't get me to Extensions with "EXTENSIONS" Syntax..

Comment: For anyone who's looking for URL Schemes for Settings App Deep Linking - this is a link to a article containing the most accurate & updated schemes that I found, right: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72785618/ios-settings-app-url-scheme-for-settings-safari-extensions

P.s - Still not found the exact path for 'Settings -> Safari -> Extensions',
so, any help will be Great!
Good luck y'all!

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:
App-Prefs:SAFARI&path=WEB_EXTENSIONS/**extensionName**

**extensionName** is your extension name URL encoded